# 429 errors returned from Google Translate when using googletrans library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

I have a problem with the library [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/). So I am working in translating a dataframe. I just download a the data from Google Cloud Storage buckets and store it in DataFrames -> I select one column to translate and there you go. I used this to translate:

```py
from googletrans import Translator, constants

def translator(text, language):
    """
    Function that receives the text we want to translate and the chosen language specified by the user and returns
    the translation
    Parameters:
    -----------
    text:
        - The string of text we want to translate
    language:
        - Specified by the user, into which language they want to translate
    """
    translate = Translator(raise_exception=True)

    # They are stored such as 'en':'english'
    def dest_language(val):
        for key, value in constants.LANGUAGES.items():
            # all values in lower case. If not we get ValueError: invalid destination language
            if value == val.lower():
                return key
        return 'Key Not Found'

    return translate.translate(text=text, dest=dest_language(language)).text
```

The problem comes when I try to translate a looooot of samples. I have 9749 samples (rows of DataFrame) to translate which each sample has more or less 5k characters and when I am trying to translate the 2000is sample I get an error. This is the code I made (the threshold is because I can’t translate more than 5k, don’t know why):

```py
# Data = All DataFrame
# tr = DataFrame with the selected column
tr = Data.loc[:, [column_translation]]

# Make a threshold to divide the text
threshold = 5000

tr.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
l = []
for i in range(len(tr)):
    if len(tr.loc[i,column_translation]) < threshold:
        l.append(TR(text=tr.loc[i,column_translation], language="spanish"))
        print(f"{i+1} out of {len(tr)}")
```

An this is the error I get when I get to 2000ish samples:

> Exception: Unexpected status code "429" from ('translate.google.com',)
> and <Response [200]>

Which I do not understand how I can get 429 error and then a 200 response… Do you know why is this happening? I mean the HTTP code is telling me that my IP got blocked for so many requests but I do not understand why.

Furthermore, what is the difference between using googletrans and [google-cloud-translate](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-translate/)?

Answer (score 0):

[googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/#:%7E:text=Note%20on%20library%20usage) is an unofficial library using the web API of [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com) and also is not associated with Google.
It is crawling the translate web page, which is why you eventually received a 429 error message which is the **HTTP 429 Too Many Request** status code.
These kind of unofficial libraries are unstable and will eventually get blocked.

To get a stable application you should use the [official library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-translate/) which calls the [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).
The Cloud Translation API has [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas) but it takes care of handling these errors with retries using [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

Comment: Yes, but official library doesn't even provide synonyms, multiple translation or a confidence for a given translation in a "dictionary" mode. Using Google Translate is simply superior.